# Exception handling guidance in a Java EE 5 Web App

Tags: java, jsf

I’ve been surprised by how hard it is to find best practices for this on the web since it must be such a common problem.

App is based on Java 1.5 – JSF 1.2 with Faclets, Seam, JPA, Hibernate.  Some Web Service calls.  Some JMS.

I’m after  general recommendations for Exception handling.  There are roughly 3 approaches I’ve seen used but I’ve never been that sure which one is better.  Assuming you can’t recover from an error do you:
1) Log the error when it occurs and re-throw it?
2) Log it when it occurs and throw some sort of generic exception?
3) Let it bubble up and then handle it in a generic exception handling servlet or similar.

I’ve tended to use option 2 on previous systems where the architecture has been fairly simple – an adaptor layer talking to various 3rd party systems throws and adaptor exception if it gets an error back and so on.  We can display a nice clean message to the user on the screen and keep the details in a log. Here though the architecture is a lot more complex and I’m wondering how well it would work in practice.  So I’m interested to know what you prefer and why.

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming you can’t recover from an error...

Assuming this error is not a functional error, I log the error and wrap the exception in an (custom)  unchecked exception and let the framework/container handle it (so option 2).
I like to do it his way because:

- I like to use container managed transactions and I want the container to do its job (i.e. rollback any transaction) so throwing a runtime exception is the way to go.
- It minimize the exception handling work.
- It make the reporting to the user easy to handle in a generic way.

If it's a functional error (i.e. an alternative flow in a use case), I log the error and wrap the exception in a (custom) checked exception because I want the caller to handle it specifically as the problem is part of the use case.

In both case, I use a root exception for each hierarchy, namely `TechnicalException` and `FunctionalException`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Anyone got any other opinions on this?

Comment: @charles Pretty surprising to see only one answer here, I was expecting lots of them.

Comment: Yes - I'm surprised to.  It is a good answeer though so maybe we've put everyone off!  Actually the method I see most often when I do code audits is 3 - Let it bubble up and then handle it in a generic exception handling servlet or similar - though it probobly doens't consitute best practice.

Comment: @charles If I can't recover from an error, I prefer to wrap it in an unchecked exception so that it can bubble *transparently* (the callers don't have to add the `throws`).